# VLC interactive zoom level?

Tags: vlc-media-player, zoom

Is there any way to edit/tune **interactive zoom level** in VLC ? it seems that the default zoom is 200%. I would like to make it 150 %.

I found something here [Fine control over zoom and aspect ratio in VLC player](https://superuser.com/questions/40063/fine-control-over-zoom-and-aspect-ratio-in-vlc-player)

but this cmd procedure seems complex when I want to play multiple videos and also **this procedure does not work**.

thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW [MPCHC has advanced interactive zoom controls using the number pad.](https://imgur.com/a/dZ9ve)

Answer (score 7):

It's super easy to miss, especially on a bright background, but there's a **zoom-level meter** below the bottom-left corner of the zoom controls - which allows you to easily control the zoom-level.

[image: zoom-level controls]

Comment: They definitely need to make it bigger. I've been using interactive zoom on quite a few occasions for the past two years and I never even noticed the zoom controls

Answer (score 0):

You can change the zoom level by dragging the white slider up and down, it's inside the red square on the left, about 1/4 of the way down on those imgur images in the replies.

Answer (score -2):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- At the bottom left under **Show settings** select **All**
- In **Video**, set **Zoom video** to **1,5**

[image: Advanced Preferences]

Works as intended for me, even with multiple files.

[image: Zoom to 150%]

Comment: Hlw, bro, Thanks for the response. I want to edit **interactive zoom** level. like this one in this image. Is it possible ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BhEv.png

Comment: Yes, start VLC from command line using the command `vlc --video-filter "magnify" yourfile.avi`

Comment: yes bro, but this opens the video in 2x zoomed mode. I want the zoom to be   1.5x.

Comment: This opens the video in the last used zoom mode. 1.5 in my case. Use `vlc --video-filter "magnify" --zoom 1.5 yourfile.avi` to have it opened in magnify and zoom mode.

Comment: I understood that I did not make myself clear well. This command zooms the video by resizing the window size to 1.5x, this is not what I want to do. I want to resize the zoom saction in the video. its is showed in this image https://imgur.com/hKAoSyx

Thanks.