# Is it possible to change the aspect ratio of the zoom box in vlc media player?

Tags: vlc-media-player

My lectures are recorded in zoom and two screens are stacked together (the camera which records the lecturer and the screen with the presentation). There is an option to zoom in (Tools -> Effects and Filters -> Video Effects -> Interactive Zoom). However, the "zoom box" has the same aspect ratio as the original video. [Here is a screenshot of the typical recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2E3v.png). But if I want to zoom in on one of the screens, it would be more appropriate to change the aspect ratio, so that it fits onto the screen of my laptop. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The video was streamed out using 2 cameras but you received it as one sigle all-in package. VLC player (or any other player I'm aware of) contains no partial zoom facility.

What you want to do requires an actual video editor. There are many capable Open Source applications, such as OpenShot. Comparing the features of different applications you should be able to find one that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer: this is a duplicate of [Fine control over zoom and aspect ratio in VLC player](https://superuser.com/questions/40063/fine-control-over-zoom-and-aspect-ratio-in-vlc-player) - just use the "Crop" function and VLC will zoom automatically. I'm sure you've figured that out by now, almost 2 years later...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).